# error in inflating layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, fatal-error

I want to add footer in my listview by inflating a different layout.
here is my code ...

```
View loadMoreView, loading_img;

loading_img = ((LayoutInflater)this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.loading_img, null, false);

loadMoreView = ((LayoutInflater)this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.load_more_btn, null, false);
```

Here is xml file loading_img.xml code ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/loading_img"
        android:src="@mipmap/progress_bar_default"
        android:background="@color/pd_color1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

but it shows error....

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.plexusd.plexusd/com.plexusd.plexusd.Notification}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                     at com.plexusd.plexusd.Notification.onCreate(Notification.java:104)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6337)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                     at com.plexusd.plexusd.Notification.onCreate(Notification.java:104) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6337) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                     at com.plexusd.plexusd.Notification.onCreate(Notification.java:104) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6337) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2971336 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
                                                                     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:831)
                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:775)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifDrawable.<init>(GifDrawable.java:248)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifDrawable.<init>(GifDrawable.java:160)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifDrawable.<init>(GifDrawable.java:95)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifViewUtils.setResource(GifViewUtils.java:53)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifViewUtils.getResourceId(GifViewUtils.java:41)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifViewUtils.initImageView(GifViewUtils.java:29)
                                                                     at pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView.<init>(GifImageView.java:41)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                     at com.plexusd.plexusd.Notification.onCreate(Notification.java:104) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6337) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

07-06 00:23:56.956 24424-24424/com.plexusd.plexusd I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24424 SIG: 9

Comment: It seems that the error is in the XML file itself.

Comment: I have edited the question and given the xml file. Please .....

Answer (score 0):

The cause is shown down at the bottom of stacktrace:

`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2971336 free bytes and 2MB until OOM`

The suggested ways to deal with OOM are:

> 1. If you are working with large-sized GIFs you can subsample them, see: #284 (comment)
> 2. You can use tools like MAT, or Memory Monitor in Android Studio to locate potential causes.
> 3. You can increase available heap space by using android:largeHeap="true" in AndroidManifest.xml or dividing app to
>      separate processes (by adding android:process tags) but those
>      workarounds may cause side-effects.

https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/issues/326